# Is neon a molecular element?

Tags: molecules

Does the chemical element neon consist of a molecule? For example, oxygen consist of two atoms together. But is that the same with neon?

Comment: Are you asking if an atom of Neon is classified as a "molecule"? Or are you asking if there are molecules which contain Ne atoms?

Answer (score 5):

Since neon is a noble gas, it has its full share of valence electrons, which makes it unlikely to bond with other atoms.  Under certain conditions other noble gases, specifically xenon and krypton, can form compounds in extreme temperatures and pressures.

See the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noble_gas) article on noble gases,

> [the noble gases] are all monatomic gases under standard conditions

and, according to the article

> Neutral compounds in which helium and neon are involved in chemical bonds have not been formed

Comment: I think the question is asking if a monoatomic molecule is ... well ... a molecule.

Comment: @ManishEarth Hmm, well, true, that's how it reads, but I think this is what the OP is actually asking about.  Thanks, I have an "it's" problem, doctors are checking into it :P

Comment: Then what keeps solid, frozen neon together?

Comment: @EricBrown that's a different (and interesting) question :)

Comment: @EricBrown So known van der Waals forces. They have different nature than covalent bonding, and are much, much weaker.

Comment: @permeakra It seems to me that a "van der Waals force" is a magical force that is invoked to describe bonding in situations that don't fit the empirical valence rules. Since these rules don't describe every circumstance, I conclude they are somewhat bogus, and there is little sense creating a force to shore things up.  It's electrostatics in each and every bonding circumstance.

Comment: @EricBrown They are not magical. main type of vdw forces are London dispersion forces and comes from electron correlation, so are very difficult to describe in a simple manner. wiki has a reasonable simple explanation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_dispersion_force

Comment: @permeakra The whole gamut of chemical bonding topologies can be found with variational methods using only the K.E., P.E. in its simplest form, and the antisymmetry requirement of the wfn. My point is that many of these anomalies are not really anomalies at all, if one did not have prior knowledge of the empirical valence rules (e.g. noble gases make 0 bonds)

Answer (score 2):

Neon exists as single atoms in its elemental form. It is a noble gas, and as @jonsca said, that means (for various reasons) that it is extremely difficult for it to form bonds (I don't know of any neon compounds).

I think the confusion may be coming from a missing definition: what is a molecule?

A **molecule** is two or more atoms joined by covalent bonds.

Since neon exists as solitary atoms, it is not a molecular element.

Comment: http://goldbook.iupac.org/M04002.html